How to get my sites from Sharepoint with phpSPO
I'm trying to use phpSPO to get the files from our sharepoint 'My Sites'.
Getting the 'Shared Documents' is working with getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents"),
but when I try to use getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("sites/office") it is not retrieving any files/folders.
Here is a code sample I am using:
$parentFolderUrl="Shared Documents"; => this works
// $parentFolderUrl="sites/office"; => this does not work
// $parentFolderUrl="/sites/office"; => this does not work

function forEachFile(Folder $parentFolder, $recursive, callable $action, $level=0)
{
    $files = $parentFolder->getFiles()->get()->executeQuery();
    /** @var File $file */
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $action($file, $level);
    }

    if ($recursive) {
        /** @var Folder $folder */
        $folders = $parentFolder->getFolders()->get()->executeQuery();
        // foreach ($parentFolder->getFolders() as $folder) {
        foreach ($folders as $folder) {
            forEachFile($folder, $recursive, $action, $level++);
        }
    }
}

$rootFolder = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl($parentFolderUrl);

forEachFile($rootFolder, true, function (File $file,$level){
  echo $level, ":", $file->getServerRelativeUrl(), "<br>", PHP_EOL;
});

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

I hate to answer my own question, but the reason was the initial connection.
After changing the url from 'https://.sharepoint.com' to 'https://.sharepoint.com/sites/office', I was able to display the files.
$siteUrl = "https://<subdomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/office";
$credentials = new ClientCredential($settings['ClientId'], $settings['ClientSecret']);
$ctx = (new ClientContext($siteUrl))->withCredentials($credentials);

I hope this answer helps others

This is because https://.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename is a specific site, and https://.sharepoint.com is the landing site, so the content cannot be obtained.
